# Using Symbol as DOM / HTMLElement attributes

Tags: javascript

In general custom HTML element attributes are discouraged but in some cases one have the choice between either having a collection of nodes that one saves and traverse for comparison or setting a property. As for the former that is often enough not a good choice.

Usually I would use `dataset` for this, but what if that is not a good option due to the script being used on any site where one have no control of what that site itself does?

Say one want to tag all `<video>` elements with a custom status property could one use `Symbol()` attached directly to the element? I have tested using `Symbol()` on `dataset` but it seems to be *lost* sometimes. As in: I can set it, log it, next call it is sometimes there, sometimes not. (Which also makes a use-case harder to make) Not sure why. Might have something to do with it being a media element? `Symbol()` is perhaps not valid as *"dataset property name"*?

Question the is if it is OK to set it directly on the element?

```js
const symbol = Symbol.for("test");
// in some function:

// instead of:
some_element.dataset[symbol] = "foo";
// do:
some_element[symbol] = "foo";
```

Have not had any trouble with the latter (as in property disappearing).

Or could one perhaps use something like:

```js
Object.defineProperty(element, symbol, {
        readonly: true,
        value: "foo"
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your worry is that the site you have no control over could theoretically modify the data attribute - the same could occur with a symbol if the other site was really intent on breaking things.

```js
const element = document.querySelector('div');

// Your code
const symbol = Symbol.for("test");
element[symbol] = "foo";

// Site's code
const [sym] = Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(element);
element[sym] = "bar";

// Your code, later
console.log(element[symbol]);
```

```html
<div></div>
```

or, the site itself could use `Symbol.for` too.

```js
const element = document.querySelector('div');

// Your code
const symbol = Symbol.for("test");
element[symbol] = "foo";

// Site's code
element[Symbol.for('test')] = "bar";

// Your code, later
console.log(element[symbol]);
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Defining the property as readonly could work, but it'd also make *you* unable to alter the property later, which you might find would eventually be a problem.

A better solution would be to, instead of putting a property onto the object, to create your own collection that associates the elements with your custom values. If your own collection is scoped to only your own script (like with an IIFE), it'll then be impossible for other scripts to interfere with. This is a great place for a WeakMap. For example:

```js
// Your code
(() => {
  const map = new WeakMap();
  const element = document.querySelector('div');
  // Set the value:
  map.set(element, 'foo');
  
  // Retrieve the value:
  console.log(map.get(element));
})();
```

```html
<div></div>
```

The WeakMap values will continue to work and be unmodifiable by outside sources as long as the elements still exist in memory.

Comment: Was not aware of `WeakMap`, but that looks promising. Concern was to have a collection of elements that might be removed from DOM or what not, but never garbage'd due to it's ref in my collection. If I understand WeakMap correctly that should not be an issue with it.

Comment: That's why a WeakMap is better than a Map in this situation - WeakMap keys will not prevent their keys from being garbage collected (unlike a Map, which will).

Comment: Yes, a `Map` was a no-go due to garbage refs. That's why I pondered about `Symbol` as  a compromise though not 100% "safe". But `WeakMap` looks golden.